# Creating a type / interface that references itself

Tags: typescript

**Here's a simple example:**

> [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUzLKBPA6gJwIYAOByOATKQDwAqKAHlKgCYDOiA3ogNoDSiMSAa2QY4wRFQC6ALnYBYAFCIliIRmYyAgjnwYKq0eIB8AGgXLEwMDIAUzOABs4MqjwmcA5KubuJASkQAvIaIeGAYpvIAvoiRhtZQzv5sZso4yFAgOEhQCpEKEAjMUIgAbvgA7oEoaDCYuITEZKTWyYrKeADmyDKt5uZeMpwSEX3Kljb+QYgAzNMpSpEjymB4ALbdcm2jA1zD833jiNaTwe5QABZwq3jeSwt3iGAgqwBGJADKUDj8HT37-cJ1Fx3J1kD4HuZDrYHHATog7I59otcr4gA)

Here's the issue:

> (parameter) solo: unknown

```
function entityWrapper22<T extends { [K in keyof T]: {
    keys: Array<keyof T>,
    fn: (solo: T[K]['keys']) => any,
} }>(t: T) {
    return t
}
const vraw = entityWrapper22({
    age: {
        keys: [],
        fn: () => 33
    },
    name: {
        keys: [],
        fn: () => 'thomas',
    },
    numberString: {
        keys: ['age'],
        fn: (solo) => solo
    },
})
```

**More complicated example:**

I have a function `entityWrapper` and I am trying to type it so that the function (second parameter to `get.every`) is typed with the return value from the property with the same name.

For instance, `{ name }` should be type `string` or even `thomas` because of its inferred type.

```
const raw = entityWrapper({
    age: get.every([], () => 33),
    name: get.every([], () => 'thomas'),
    numberString: get.every(['name'], ({ name }) => '212'),
})
```

I've created two attempts to create a type that reference's itself both dont work as expected

> [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=70&ssc=60&pln=69&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqALYA7AglAcwB40A%20OAXnTlBhwBMBnOABSggFsBLR4Ir7ADNgUOAFVyAfnFwAXOgCwAKGWhIsBMlQAxLlEYx8xNDRB1sTOAENsichWVwn1Wg2YBtAcNEAlADRwAHTBNojuALrhcNI%20co7OJq4WHlHSAK4WwIICwPRxSs7oANzKykgocACyVmA%20wDBpUNhoWoz4UFaIRPFOiWZu1rZ%20PTJJlu2dRADWwIgQguikyvZwAN4jhe4A0nAC4u7YaRwARiKR8mjb4e4A5MAAbiKIN1FjzAAU78GBVoSM8qEIgBKSjkUIg6SYHBGIh1BpNFooEhXW4PJ4vUjkeTYNFQZQAX1KSgA9MTrDA6BwwPAAIxEgR0KCCKwAY1QAFFsDAuEgSKZzJZOdzeWRyKs4CN3DNEPIDFABARwvIAJKUkhLJSElRKBkiZlsuCq4AcPlvOBCnldUVrEbS-5wCZdaXzRbDArORicYCSeTaDIs7kQbBuwrZfQwH1wP3YANcIMjXGISPvT0AGwg8mqtXqjWarUdJACMAwPFudoxIIoYKGBKJpPJlOpcAATBLteUOVzLUaTX0BcxQit1u6nNtdtg4M6FmglTaR4VJ7N7QWp66Nh6vZHo7GgyGF04wwYt-7A9h105E8m0xmqjU4bnEcA2lAOlaApcttcbuXwqRK9XED3JwtS1ZR6xZRooBwGBU0QOA0kYBVzS7JAe2UQQTzjCdoMtAB1DowBQKBTX6ZJkOFRAe3VUh3hgC4QWHQooPhCcYFrbUWSDAw4AIepKDnQpE3kIhcACAAhch3jteRRJoR4oBlOAxP-OB3nFO0AkTOB8SBIC4E9DhgGE2SJNU6SHQCAyjKUlS1MXRBGEsr1tN0kZDzouARPEyTzNk9z5GU0FVPUpcAncly3VApROOwbiIH4xjnCsXj5F4mBAkTd4IgCd4VIAZjy1z52wKxDNS%20oMvkxAsvCHKVJuYtOCsRgbiKwo6AMcr0sy24SsMl4cvFPrUB0oLhqKqKOzge5%20Kze8EXzF9Jg7F0IACXrSuADEyi0ax%20ItVC1RWhYIA1Kbjn2lCumOuBTqJGLuPuDoAHd%20JwpB8JqIi1JGZLrLSyqnhquqgoKtrnGGrrAYU4HVPqxqOGa1q9OJAAqVGNlR9AFKQmB4rShAS2YZjczgFkrFTVNjlZKY4DAdgiNgzQUDyaneHoAIg0J1ASaaNsFyx%204KbSJ9boWG4-puQY8huQ4ThEKWEKQm45pzBaUGfV8bkx4kRjl04oAAZRgeVsAIKGetlzaBuCuBhpcoKbmbGlm2RgkgWUIA)

I have one example here, it's a `type`.

```
type EntityItem<T extends any> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        keys: Array<keyof T>,
        some?: Function,
        first?: Function
        every?: (solo: MapReturnTypesArray<T, T[K]['keys']>) => any,
    }
}
```

And another here which is using `interface`.

```
interface Entity<T extends Entity<T>> { 
    [key: string]: Item<T>
}

interface Item<T extends Entity<T>> {
    keys: Array<keyof T>,
    some?: Function,
    first?: Function
    every?: (solo: MapReturnTypesArray<T, this['keys']>) => any,
}
```

Both of these seem to not work correctly and register the keys as `never[]` within every.

For more context all `get.every` does is assign props to an object.

```
const get = {
    every: <A, B> (keys: A, every: B) => ({ keys, every }),
    some: <A, B> (keys: A, some: B) => ({ keys, some }),
    first: <A, B> (keys: A, first: B) => ({ keys, first }),
}
```

The error is:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'MapReturnTypesArray

Comment: Does a builder like [this](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/TypeScript?at=5dcedca3e75b2d5a19daaf7c) work for you?  I doubt you'll ever get the kind of return-value based self-inference; it's a [design limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29771).

Comment: I added a link to the issue I'm having with the builder. Has to do with the arguments of `every` when called.