# Circular type referenced in its own initializer

Tags: typescript, generics, circular-reference

Below I believe I am running into an issue with circular typing, this is because `MethodReturns` is being run for `user`'s `this.every` and then `userId`'s `this.every`.

Here's the error:

> 'user' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.(7022)

Here's the link:

> [PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=54&pln=18&pc=67#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqALYA7AglAcwB40A%20OAXnTlBhwBMBnOABSggFsBLR4Ir7ADNgUOAFVyAfnFwAXOgCwAKGWhIsBMlQAxLlEYx8xNDRB1sTOAENsichWVwn1Wg2YBtAcNEAlADRwAHTBNojuALrhcNI%20co7OJq4WHlHSAK4WwIICwPRxSs7oANzKquDQ8EgocACywDAYEPQ%209WlQ2IxEAMKm5pahATW9bnD4UFaIRADWwIgQgnBdpPZwAN7xTu4A0nACte7YaRwARiKR8l3b4e4A5ILYN1FJlgAUL8GBVoSM8qERAJSUcihQHSXT6QyEEhYPBQlowNrYNBabpXW73R7LcjybDAABuImUAF9SkoqqgxLxRFRVrt6DijqcoAE0mkuPS4AYoAICAFsFYOMB5FyeXASUoAMYQDrwAj1SkiABCiAAknkqC92QyTiJ-vIFdTyC9aeyWWyOTcAIwAJgAzAAWG58gVCuA3BqcKyMG5i-7KKUyuBymAG5Vic2UOAvVlazkwbnYAh68RUoFRk0cy1m01wfmC%20TuxocL0%20ol%20lSSgA2XuYAFEQAKwJXUOsK4V8SJEHASMNkqMoONJjM5gt643m6RBr3LHUPc1Wu1OmOOE3gAEyAEAOKkF5WeRoALHeQvRgQSsQeQ1QEUcibwGtwqFAD0T7gUAX2DgggyEpgXGlUbJpuawbI%20L6Pu%20CLtHAxzGkS1jMFeCFwJuoHPq%204qPs4kGImscDDj81gBPc8jHJhzjiqBBgdpGDQ8IEHZQIgLy3AA7hA8yPAExpwOx8y%20mmfELAA1HAlrloUgoQKxtEYPRjHMRE3HXuQ4mgUJsnyQSTEsTcUmsVx6ZwPpAk3sZwDSXAolqW2zhpKmVB0YwDHaYpNz2SIaqGTxHlQGqvr6g55DBqGqr0NGVJqv8El2ZF6oIHJzkKbpvnebSvkBbmjIiGmvmBOy5bEsoQA)

Here's the code:

```
export type ThenArg<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T

export type FirstArg<T extends any> =
    T extends [infer R, ...any[]] ? R :
    T extends [] ? undefined :
    T;

export type MethodReturns<C extends any, M extends Array<keyof C>> = {
    [K in M[number]]: C[K]['fn'] extends ((...args: any[]) => any) ? FirstArg<ThenArg<ReturnType<C[K]['fn']>>> : never
}

type User = { id: number, uuid: string, name: string }
const getUserById = (id: number): User => ({ id, uuid: '1234', name: 'thomas' })
const getUserByUuid = (uuid: string): User => ({ id: 1, uuid, name: 'thomas' })

class Example {

    every <T extends Array<keyof Example>, M extends MethodReturns<Example, T>, G>(a: T, b: (solo: M) => G) {
        // return function (): G {
        //     return b({} as M) as G
        // }
        return { keys: a, fn: b}
    }

    steve = this.every(['woof'], ({ woof }) => woof + 1)
    meow = this.every([], () => 1)
    woof = this.every(['meow'], ({ meow }) => meow + 1)

    user = this.every(['userId'], ({ userId }) => getUserById(userId))
    userId = this.every(['user'], ({ user }) number => user.id)

}
```

Is there a way to have this work syntactically, and not cause an issue. As you can see above I am typing those return values, but it still isn't doing the trick:

Ideally I could provide an optional type to `this.every` that would allow `MethodReturns` to somehow use that instead if it's available.

```
class Example {
    user = this.every<number>(['userId'], ({ userId }) => getUserById(userId))
    userId = this.every<User>(['user'], ({ user }) number => user.id)
}
```

I would accept any other syntax as an answer as well.

Comment: Is this question meaningfully different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58871039/creating-a-type-interface-that-references-itself)?  I'm inclined to close one of these as a duplicate.

Comment: The other question has to do with referencing types from within a single object. This has do with a circular issue and how to mitigate it hopefully with this optional type generic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to manually annotate your properties.  This can probably be streamlined with a type alias of the proper type, like make this:

```
type PropThing<T, K extends keyof Example> =
    { keys: K[], fn: (solo: MethodReturns<Example, K[]>) => T }
```

and then the following should prevent errors:

```
user: PropThing<User, "userId"> = this.every(['userId'], ({ userId }) => getUserById(userId))
userId: PropThing<number, "user"> = this.every(['user'], ({ user }) => user.id)
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqALYA7AglAcwB40A+OAXnTlBhwBMBnOABSggFsBLR4Ir7ADNgUOAFVyAfnFwAXOgCwAKGWhIsBMlQAxLlEYx8xNDRB1sTOAENsichWVwn1Wg2YBtAcNEAlADRwAHTBNojuALrhcNI+co7OJq4WHlHSAK4WwIICwPRxSs7oANzKquDQ8EgocACywDAYEPQ+9WlQ2IxEAMKm5pahATW9bnD4UFaIRADWwIgQgnBdpPZwAN7xTu4A0nACte7YaRwARiKR8l3b4e4A5ILYN1FJlgAUL8GBVoSM8qERAJSUcihQHSXT6QyEEhYPBQlowNrYNBabpXW73R7LcjybDAABuImUAF9SkoqqgxLxRFRVrt6DijqcoAE0mkuPS4AYoAICAFsFYOMB5FyeXASUoAMYQDrwAj1SkiABCiAAknkqC92QyTiJ-vIFdTyC9aeyWWyOTcAIwAJgAzAAWG58gVCuA3BqcKyMG5i-7KKUyuBymAG5Vic2UOAvVlazkwbnYAh68RUoFRk0cy1m01wfmC+TuxocL0+ol+lRkrSsdhgTA8kgBHbPZgzOYLACiIAFYAANsB7Bs1nBWz84FsIgF7vIXowID2IPI6h7mq12p1O92+42IqRARRyCZxf6e17mBuOL3UOsK4V8SJJokzCMxhNprN5nBz5fSINhslavUjQrgia5EF+W7oD+cAAOKkC8VjyGgATHNOs7zoue7kNBgLXoUhQAPT4XAUCrtgcCCBkEowFw0pRsm0FrIOBFEYUJEgWRxzGkS1jMDUgJejBTHOIRYpCU4bGIkOI6-JO2DyMcokFM4R5KU4Bh3pGDQ8IEd5QIgLy3AA7hA8yPAExpwMZH5lmmVkLAA1HAlrloUgoQIZmkYNpun6ROdFps5g52Z53kEnpBk3G5hlmemcBRb6abxY5gU3s4aRUvIbAQLWXmJkQBoBAAROlIhqoVKxaYwOlhb5NwlVAaoxRZ9Vqgl+5BvKVLKmq0ZUmq-wuWlfUcllOX1ocOrMnAxVUuVIVVT5EX1U1tL1W15D1YE7LlsSyhAA)