# Chain functions and infer types from previous return

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to type the arguments of each one of these functions below, from the corresponding keys declared in the previous chain?

```
const helloWorld = example(
    ({}) => ({ greeting: 'Hello', name: 'Thomas' }),
    ({ greeting, name }) => ({ clean: `${greeting} ${name}` }),
    ({ clean }) => ({ cleanLength: clean.length }),
    ({ name }) => ({ nameLength: name.length }),
)
```

I have this `CheckFuncs` generic [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910250/type-tuple-so-that-function-chain-has-valid-parameter-and-return-types) that checks if the types of from each function line up with each other.

```
type Tail<T extends readonly any[]> =
    ((...a: T) => void) extends ((h: any, ...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;

type CheckFuncs<T extends readonly ((x: any) => any)[]> = { [K in keyof T]:
    K extends keyof Tail<T> ? (
        [T[K], Tail<T>[K]] extends [(x: infer A) => infer R, (x: infer S) => any] ? (
            [R] extends [S] ? T[K] : (x: A) => S
        ) : never
    ) : T[K]
}

function journey<T extends readonly ((x: any) => any)[]>(...t: CheckFuncs<T>) {

}
```

This is a little different from that.

Here we can assume a couple of things:

- Each function must take only one {} argument
- Each function must return a {}
- The argument must be declare within the chain before it is used or passed into the created function.

The ideal syntax:

```
const helloWorld = example(
    ({ greeting, name }) => ({ clean: `${greeting} ${name}` }),
    ({ clean }) => ({ cleanLength: clean.length }),
    ({ name }) => ({ nameLength: name.length }),
)

helloWorld({ greeting: 'Hello', name: 'Thomas' })
```

Is this possible?

---

Also interested in key'd version:

```
const helloWorld = mac({
    clean: ({ greeting, name }) => `${greeting} ${name}`,
    cleanLength: ({ clean }) => clean.length,
    nameLength: ({ name }) => name.length,
})
```

Here's an attempt but:

> 'a' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

```
const JourneyKeyed = <T extends JourneyKeyed.Objects<T>>(a: T) => {
    return a
}

const helloWorld = JourneyKeyed({
    greeting: ({ name }) => name === 'bob' ? 'Get out!' : 'Welcome',
    fullGreeting: ({ greeting, name }) => `${greeting} ${name}`,
})


namespace JourneyKeyed {
    type ThenArg<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T
    type FirstArg<T extends any> =
        T extends [infer R, ...any[]] ? R :
        T extends [] ? undefined :
        T;
    type KeyedReturns<C, M extends Array<keyof C>> = {
        [K in M[number]]: C[K] extends ((...args: any[]) => any) ? FirstArg<ThenArg<ReturnType<C[K]>>> : never
    }
    type AllKeyedReturns<T> = KeyedReturns<typeof helloWorld, Array<keyof typeof helloWorld>>
    export type Objects<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]: (a: AllKeyedReturns<T[K]>) => T[K] extends Func ? ReturnType<T[K]> : never }
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=41#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-k5zXh69bgcRx5PUCJTb6YPYnK53J45q73V6fX7F36V843B48OJ2dRru5YMPeAIhCIlc7GEU71BWWpVeHI96MEuyJLYlkEcx38OdIHIVNRGLeRUydbkyQ1YBZTApsvggttO3iNBe3RAczCAA)

Comment: This isn't really a "chain", is it?  Each argument is dependent on *all* preceding arguments, not just the previous one.

Comment: @jcalz yes that is correct, not sure what to call it.

Comment: I'm going to have to give up on this for now, it's too messy.  One thing I notice though is that a callback like `({ x, y } => z)` is going to give you implicit `any` types for `x` and `y` unless you annotate like `({ x, y }: {x: string, y: number} => z)`, and it's quite likely this will even be true if the compiler "should" be able to infer the types of `x` and `y` from previous callbacks in the tangled-chain-thing.  Not sure how you will deal with that.

Comment: @jcalz yeah I tried the key'd version but got `'a' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly ugly and I don't think I have the energy  to explain it.  It's messy enough that I'd strongly suggest abandoning anything that requires a "reduce" operation on tuple types in favor of a [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) instead.  I'll just show a sketch of what I'm doing first.  Here's the code:

```
// extend as needed I guess
type LT = [never, 0, 0 | 1, 0 | 1 | 2, 0 | 1 | 2 | 3, 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4,
  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5, 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6, 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7
];
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
type UI<U> = UnionToIntersection<U> extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
type P0<T> = T extends (x: infer A) => any ? A : never;
type Ret<T> = T extends (x: any) => infer R ? R : never;
type Idx<T, K, D = never> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : D;

type ScanFuncs<T extends readonly ((x: any) => any)[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (x: UI<ReturnType<Idx<T, Idx<LT, K>>> | P0<T[0]>>) => Ret<T[K]>
}

function coalesce<T extends readonly ((x: any) => any)[]>(
  ...args: T & ScanFuncs<T>
): (x: P0<T[0]>) => UI<ReturnType<T[number]> | P0<T[0]>>;
function coalesce(...args: readonly ((x: any) => any)[]) {
  return (x: any) => args.reduce((a, s) => Object.assign(a, s(a)), x)
}
```

Fundamentally you're checking each function in the tuple against all the preceding functions, so you need something like: for a given index key `K` from the tuple `T`, give me `T[EverythingLessThan<K>]` and manipulate it.  There's no simple way to represent `EverythingLessThan<K>`, so I've made a tuple called `LT` with hardcoded values for `K` up to `"8"`.  It can be extended as needed, or replaced with some clever-yet-unsupported recursive type, as long as neither of them make it near production code for which I am responsible.

The `ScanFuncs` type alias converts a tuple `T` of one-arg function types into a compatible type, by comparing each function `T[K]` to another function whose return type is unchanged, but whose parameter type is the intersection of the first function's parameter type and all the prior functions return types'.  I'm using `UnionToIntersection` in there, which might do bizarre things if your functions involve unions themselves.  It could be guarded against, but with even more complexity, so I'm not bothering.

I implemented your `example`, which I called `coalesce` for want of a more inspired name, as a function which takes a tuple of one-arg callbacks of type `T`, checks it with `ScanFuncs<T>`, and returns a one-arg function whose parameter type is that of `T[0]` and whose return type is the intersection of `T[0]` and all the return types of `T`.  Let's demonstrate it working:

```
const f = coalesce(
  ({ x, y }: { x: number, y: string }) => ({ z: y.length === x }),
  ({ z }: { z: boolean }) => ({ v: !z }),
  ({ y }: { y: string }) => ({ w: y.toUpperCase() })
)
const r = f({ x: 9, y: "newspaper" })
/* const r: {
    x: number;
    y: string;
    z: boolean;
    v: boolean;
    w: string;
} */
console.log(r);
// { x: 9, y: "newspaper", z: true, v: false, w: "NEWSPAPER" }
```

Looks good.

Do note that you pretty much have to annotate your callbacks like `({x, y}: {x: number, y: string}) =>` instead of `({x, y}) =>`, since the latter will result in implicit `any` types.  Any hopes you have of having the compiler *infer* the parameter types from the return values of prior arguments should be snuffed out due to a [design limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29771) I've [mentioned to you before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58871039/creating-a-type-interface-that-references-itself#comment104030772_58871039).

---

Both this inference problem and the messiness of the tuple-reduce operation strongly hint to me that the idiomatic way to do this in TypeScript will be with a builder pattern instead.  It could look something like this:

```
type CollapseIntersection<T> =
  Extract<T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never, T>

class Coalesce<I extends object, O extends object> {
  cb: (x: I) => (I & O)
  constructor(cb: (x: I) => O) {
    this.cb = x => Object.assign({}, x, cb(x));
  }
  build() { return this.cb as (x: I) => CollapseIntersection<I & O> }
  then<T>(cb: (x: I & O) => T) {
    return new Coalesce<I, O & T>(x => {
      const io = this.cb(x);
      return Object.assign(io, cb(io));
    });
  }
}
```

That might not be the *best* implementation, but you can see that the typings are considerably less crazy.  The `CollapseIntersection` is really the only "weird" thing in there, and that's just to make ungainly types like `{x: 1, y: 2} & {z: 3} & {w: 4}` easier to work with as `{x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, w: 4}`.

The builder works by folding subsequent `then()` functions into its current callback, and keeping track only of the current output type and the overall input type.

You use it like this:

```
const f = new Coalesce(
  ({ x, y }: { x: number, y: string }) => ({ z: y.length === x })
).then(
  ({ z }) => ({ v: !z })
).then(
  ({ y }) => ({ w: y.toUpperCase() })
).build();
```

Note that the type inference works now, and you don't have to annotate `z` or `y` in the `then()` calls.  You still have to annotate `x` and `y` in the initial `new Coalesce()` argument, but that makes sense since there's nowhere for the compiler to infer it from.  And it behaves the same:

```
const r = f({ x: 9, y: "newspaper" })
/* const r: {
    x: number;
    y: string;
    z: boolean;
    v: boolean;
    w: string;
} */
console.log(r);
// { x: 9, y: "newspaper", z: true, v: false, w: "NEWSPAPER" }
```

Looks good!

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZaUCeAVArjANhAJIAuEATiCQJYD2wSA3gLABQbSSA9F0hAB5lgAEyQgoSYBAjCZSIkgDmOdByQkMMZABksSALxIA2lIBuFADRIADFetIAPkgCMdxy-cAmN0+df3AMw+Hk6ege4ALBZqnPa+-k4Bke4ArMF+oeFOEanuAGzpCUhJ2blOee4A7GoAugDcahpaSACqwHTAWLREwGTkUBDwNPQAPC0AfAYxSAAULXyCECISIMAYSAD8swDWAFytAJQGk6a01KL7ZhRHAkLCEjMze0jUwABmFPJH+idnwkdbBSXCDmciNTTIFpEMaTQxtDpdHp9AZDDowhZ3CSvD7kJAAeU2TGMAGkXgxthAMLQ3viavs8UZiTUkABfJDA0ENVicJrIAAK1hGWFhSD0tyW91m-H22M+AEFvpNVustnL2ZIQRQuTyIUgAEoQEhCkVixbLKX7ZWKsk4-WEvXqq7kbXqXVEYT8IVWYlWAAiBg1oJFpPF5opVJpei2WEZzP2vq54OaAGV4KsAGI4YDwKBCjESiTkCAgYT0fDrR7SsRra1Wow1EUsbmcElkpDh6miukW1rQg0kHDkToQkbuz1YKxjka6b3jOfuAVCozWBvja39pdM8ZqFlsJPIABaAaMMxA+0YSCrUBI5FeiisGEuODAACNPizrReAF77F+0WiEKsrLRM2nCnueSA-kgf4AcWwBWFeN53qyn5IAA7vs163sAijAdM4FEoh2H3pBv7-oB8HoZhSE4ShxxEs8wDPm+uK7s2NR7s2vJ2oYqYZlmOYjAe27sM2bwCcMDDwLQICEFAiB5qGkpFiWZYVjMVZWvRdYNjM0wAHSGSA5CKFA+x6AAZEgfHAJm2a5sKagHPsGn7IuMYrmu9FQiM-aDsOWhLkxr4UA2C6Ch5q6JmJEkdEg0mydAiAzIZ+nGaZ+wqaWwDlrMrnVhgtY1vWRxNi2SBFgOQ49lpPxiCZUD6UWwg4Mlp5WFA1p4i+ABWgwkGlUBQNQijAO1SBQKeBwHAhBw7pxnDScA15IDShgJXJyX4Re-APqyEFVsFLEPtRxF0XVMzfvsGD6YQOEkAAFgY+iGPwKEgeVl2QftRJQTBFHnZMX2mPsACEX7vdtSDrCyEGPhNNG4R+9FfRh0P6SQtAtDAWjkAAwuIEAzEcH5OWoS0rbihhvF9VYAJwnUgABEUhobAIC40zKFqFwABU8X0JT57TJwh3MVqIvQ6dd4uuVf3kXBsstiD0EK6sSucGjWEyzuSC81w5OC7Bt20IoMzkAcLo8IR+wM1LzOs+znNWFBN4qFYKtvLJAxWGjTMAHIAKIAOrJnycp8oHepc2xbCx6woCQOziBIAAQjg1D4LIuJNvuSB4wB+AcwMSIUCiknGlMoFIIHgiUEMilmpKsq4vMWwXoybYdjSLTdi0saso6mrkFYjmiYtRdDfnMmbRAo75uatC9f1VgEkpEhL31QyTGVLbwC+LlVkQ1ozAoVl4nN1cU27Qy0OQMz74f+zH-RF9MJLj3UI1+8Bm9dXdVvAa4hhqjUuiyBCVh94aWmkrNi5UXwZyzsTIklV-LqAel-fSP9xA9hfnVAu+Ai4wBLr0Mu-U0Rn3xJMOBLZHpLGNA-A+uCkDn2tFgUqktUHVVZtPRK8k55EFXiw0U4wNL0V3uVRagsSAvFoAGT+38XzQI1i2LhDAAH9UGiAsadBIFKLoDAyWH5YHzWbIbZaMi1oajQrw2eelq60z2rDG2khxYj3ttrWiyMLpXXRndRQj1nqvW5s2A4GMHpLHsZ9b8gNZgXhVuDEJnAwl0LGlDGGJ8LxoxupjbGuMCYDGQaTUJ+kEGZ2EMTaKUiLEVQDDTHattGYswgGzOAnMkncH5tfCqwtq6iyfCFZ0kt4aeMUCo+WsF1aSxVv9RWkstaIxdGyfW5ioDG3wKbc2lsea8AaUgO28NmmtI5hQJmLt9huwgB7fYXt8A+yoszIOodw6R2jqyTicc2BAA)